# blink-matching-paren not working in readline prompt

Tags: c, readline

I am making a program with an interactive prompt using the [readline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) library. I would like for the prompt to support matching parenthesis highlighting so I have set `blink-matching-paren` in `~/.initrc` with

```
set blink-matching-paren on
```

however when I use the interactive prompt, there is no matching parenthesis blinking. I am using the `#include` directives shown here:

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
```

and reading from standard input like so:

```
char* line = readline(my_prompt);
```

The linked documentation suggests that this would be sufficient, yet I am not observing the desired behavior.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are really calling the correct `readline` function, as indeed what you have done should be sufficient. Check that you are linking the correct library with the `-lreadline` compiler flag. Perhaps you are mistakenly linking a similar library (such as [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)) which also has a `readline` function and are calling the `readline` from that library instead.

Comment: This solved my problem (I was linking the wrong library).

Comment: @klutt can't until two days from now unfortunately.